# GameObject - Component hierarchy, component can access game object in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

While creating a game engine using c++, when defining a component, I was tired of writing down essential but repeated elements such as 'GameObject* parent' every time I define a new component constructor.

So I thought of a shortcut. It's debatable, and I feel it can be improved.

- When I need to create many different components, the following code is sufficient to disable the 'C6011', 'C26495' warnings?
- Any potential problems with this code?
- Is there a better way?

### concept

1. Create a component class using malloc.
2. Enter the value of component begin.
3. Call the component`s constructor.

   ```
    ComponentType* mptr = (ComponentType*)malloc(sizeof(ComponentType));
    mptr->_begin = new Initialize(owner_game_object_ptr);

    new(mptr) ComponentType(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return mptr:
   ```

### code

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Initialize;
class GameObject;
class ComponentConstructor;

struct Initialize
{
    GameObject* owner;

    Initialize() = delete;
    Initialize(const Initialize&) = delete;
    Initialize(Initialize&&) = delete;

    Initialize(GameObject* owner_game_object) :
        owner(owner_game_object)
    {}
};

class Component
{
private:
    Initialize* _begin;
public:
    __declspec(property(get = get_initialize)) Initialize* begin;
    inline const Initialize* get_initialize() { return _begin; }

public:
    Component() = default;
    virtual ~Component() = default;

    friend GameObject;
    friend ComponentConstructor;
};
class ComponentConstructor
{
    std::unique_ptr<Initialize> begin;
    Component* component;

public:
    ComponentConstructor() 
        : component(nullptr) 
    {}
    ~ComponentConstructor()
    {
        if (component != nullptr)
        {
            component->~Component();
            free(component);
        }
    }

    void make_begin(GameObject* owner)
    {
        begin = std::make_unique<Initialize>(owner);
    }
    template <typename Type, typename... Args
        , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Type, Component>::value>::type
    >
    void make_component(Args&&... args)
    {
        Type* mptr = (Type*)malloc(sizeof(Type));
        mptr->_begin = begin.get();

        new(mptr) Type(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        component = mptr;
    }
    friend GameObject;
};

/*
    for use initialize in derived component
*/
class GameObject
{
public:
    std::string name;
    GameObject(const std::string& object_name) : name(object_name)
    {}

private:
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<ComponentConstructor>> child_components;
public:
    template <typename Type, typename... Args
        , typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<Type, Component>::value>::type
    >
    Type* add_component(Args&&... args)
    {
        child_components.emplace_back();
        auto& elum = child_components.back();
        elum = std::make_unique<ComponentConstructor>();

        elum->make_begin(this);
        elum->make_component<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        return static_cast<Type*>(elum->component);
    }
    void remove_component(Component* component)
    {
    auto it = std::find_if(child_components.begin(), child_components.end(),
        [component](const std::unique_ptr<ComponentConstructor>& child_component)
        {
            return child_component->component == component;
        });

    if (it != child_components.end())
        child_components.erase(it);
    }
};
```

### use

```
class GameObjectComponent : public Component
{
    GameObjectComponent()
    {
        std::cout << "GameObjectComponent is created" << std::endl;
    }
    ~GameObjectComponent()
    {
        std::cout << "GameObjectComponent is deleted" << std::endl;
    }
    friend ComponentConstructor;
};
class CheckNameComponent : public Component
{
    CheckNameComponent()
    {
        std::cout << "CheckNameComponent is created" << std::endl;

        if (begin->owner->name == "Game object")
            begin->owner->add_component<GameObjectComponent>();
    }
    ~CheckNameComponent()
    {
        std::cout << "CheckNameComponent is deleted" << std::endl;
    }
    friend ComponentConstructor;
};


int main()
{
    GameObject object("Game object");
    object.add_component<CheckNameComponent>();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Comment: Thanks for editing - you still need to change the title to the purpose of the code, rather than your concerns about it.

Comment: Thank you for comment.

Comment: The purpose of the code is still unclear. Unless the code is for a base class of objects the code seems to be too theoretical and that would make it off-topic for code review. It is also not clear in the question why you want to use `malloc` and `free` rather than `new` and `delete`. Using `malloc` in C++ is not recommended.

Comment: Can you show us an example of how you would write a component and add it to a `GameObject` before you introduced your `ComponentConstructor` class?

Comment: Thank you for comment. After waking up and thinking about it for hours, I couldn't find any hint at all in the word theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two motivations here:

1. Remove repetition of passing the owning `GameObject*` around.
2. Ensure that `Component`s can add other components to their owning `GameObject` inside the `Component` constructor.

---

## 1 - Passing `GameObject*`s:

I wouldn't worry about having to pass the owning `GameObject*` around. Assuming our base `Component` class looks something like this:

```
class Component
{
private:

    GameObject* owner;

public:

    virtual ~Component() { }
    
    GameObject* get_owner() const { return owner; }

protected:

    explicit Component(GameObject* owner):
        owner(owner) { }

};
```

All our component classes will take the owner pointer in a constructor and pass it to their base `Component`:

```
explicit CheckNameComponent(GameObject* owner):
    Component(owner) { ... }
```

Where the GameObject pointer is passed as the first argument in `GameObject::add_component`:

```
std::make_unique<ComponentT>(this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

The only repeated "boilerplate" code here is the two lines in every component:

```
explicit CheckNameComponent(GameObject* owner):
    Component(owner) { ... }
```

This is completely fine. It's not something that needs to be replaced with a very complicated system of construction using placement new and inheritance.

---

## 2 - Adding `Component`s from `Component` constructors:

I think the problem here is with `add_component` being called recursively, e.g.:

```
CheckNameComponent()
{
    std::cout << "CheckNameComponent is created" << std::endl;

    if (begin->owner->name == "Game object")
        begin->owner->add_component<GameObjectComponent>();
}
```

We need to be careful with ordering things so that:

- We return the correct pointer from `add_component`.
- Reallocation from recursive calls doesn't move our objects in memory (which I guess is why `std::list` is used instead of `std::vector`).
- Certain rules are enforced with the order of construction of "child" components. (i.e. can a component added by an `add_component` call in a component constructor check that it's "parent" component exists on the owning game object? so could `GameObjectComponent` do `begin->owner->get_component<CheckNameComponent>`?)

That last one is kinda hard to solve. It's up to you what exactly you want to do in this situation. Since the `CheckNameComponent` constructor hasn't returned, we can't guarantee that the object is "safe" to use in `GameObjectComponent`. But we could perhaps try to guarantee that `GameObjectComponent` can get a pointer to `CheckNameComponent`.

Personally I wouldn't try to make this guarantee! I think it's fine to document that components *are not there* in the `GameObject` (and can't be accessed) until `add_component` returns successfully.

Then we can use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>>` for the components, and create the component *before* we add space for it in the component list:

```
template<class ComponentT, class... Args>
ComponentT* add_component(Args&&... args)
{
    auto component = std::make_unique<ComponentT>(this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto result = component.get();
    components.push_back(std::move(component));
    return result;
}
```

If a "child" component needs to be added, and needs access to its parent, it's up to the writer of the `Component` class to explicitly pass the relevant dependencies, e.g.:

```
explicit CheckNameComponent(GameObject* owner):
    Component(owner)
{
    if (get_owner()->name == "Game object")
        get_owner()->add_component<OtherComponent>(this); // pass the needed pointer
}

explicit OtherComponent(GameObject* owner, CheckNameComponent* check_name):
    Component(owner)
{
    // use `check_name` here... it's up to the programmer to ensure we only access valid state
}
```

---

So overall I'm not sure the added complexity is worth it. I think the same thing can be achieved like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Component;

class GameObject
{
public:

    explicit GameObject(std::string const& name):
        name(name) { }

    template<class ComponentT, class... Args>
    ComponentT* add_component(Args&&... args)
    {
        auto component = std::make_unique<ComponentT>(this, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        auto result = component.get();
        components.push_back(std::move(component));
        return result;
    }

    std::string name;

private:

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Component>> components;
};

class Component
{
private:

    GameObject* owner;

public:

    virtual ~Component() { }

    GameObject* get_owner() const { return owner; }

protected:

    explicit Component(GameObject* owner):
        owner(owner) { }

};

class OtherComponent;

class CheckNameComponent : public Component
{
public:

    explicit CheckNameComponent(GameObject* owner):
        Component(owner)
    {
        if (get_owner()->name == "Game object")
        {
            get_owner()->add_component<OtherComponent>();
        }
    }
};

class OtherComponent : public Component
{
public:

    explicit OtherComponent(GameObject* owner):
        Component(owner)
    {
        std::cout << "OtherComponent constructor\n";
    }

    ~OtherComponent()
    {
        std::cout << "OtherComponent destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        auto object = GameObject("Game object");
        object.add_component<CheckNameComponent>();
    }

    std::cout << std::flush;
}
```

---

## Some other things:

(Although I've suggested removing / changing most of your code above, here are some comments about your code as it exists at the moment).

### Naming:

`Initialize` is not a good name for a class. Classes should usually use nouns for names, not verbs. Something like `ComponentOwner` or just `ComponentBase` might be better.

The name `begin` is nearly always used in C++ for something specific (the first iterator in a sequence), so it shouldn't be used for something else. This variable should probably be named after the `Initialize` class (so `owner` or `base` if you use my suggestions above).

---

### `malloc`:

In C++ we should use the [global `operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) to allocate memory, instead of `malloc`. (And of course use `delete` instead of `free`).